# When a number is written as 0x00... what does the x mean

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Suppose I was trying to create a mask in C for bitwise operations, like

```
uint32_t Mask = 0x00000003;
```

What does the x mean? I see a lot of numbers written with that 0x format and I don't understand why and have been unable to find an explanation that really makes sense to me, maybe I'm not searching the right thing.

Comment: Search for hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a human driven Search engine. Please consider doing at least a tiny bit of research before asking such basic questions. Googling for "Numbers with 0x" gives several examples.

Answer (score 5):

it means the the number is expressed in hex , base 16 instead of decimal, based 10. For your example it makes no difference

```
uint32_t Mask = 0x00000003;
```

since 3 is 3 in both bases

but

```
uint32_t Mask = 0x00000010;  // '16' in human talk
```

is quite different from

```
uint32_t Mask = 10; // '10' in human talk
```

Note that

```
uint32_t Mask = 00000010;
```

is actually '8' in human talk because in c and c++ numeric literals starting with a zero are in octal (base 8)

You will see

```
uint32_t Mask = 0x00000003;
```

when expressing something where the value is a set of bit flags rather than a number (see the name 'mask') since hex maps nicely to a sequence of bits. You might see

```
uint32_t Mask1 = 0x00000003;
uint32_t Mask2 = 0x00000010;
uint32_t Mask3 = 0x000000C2;
```

The first one doesnt need 0x but it just looks cleaner

Comment: `00000010` is *8* in human talk - leading 0s indicate octal notation.

Comment: @JohnBode - i just reread this answer (it got an upvote) and realized the error, scrolled down to edit and saw your comment - fixed now (if a little late)

Answer (score 2):

'0x' means that the number that follows is in hexadecimal. It's a way of unambiguously stating that a number is in hex, and is a notation recognized by C compilers and some assemblers.